# Unable to open library: libnvinfer_plugin.so.8 due to libcublas.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, tensorrt

Getting the error  `Unable to open library: libnvinfer_plugin.so.8 due to libcublas.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` while trying to use tensorrt in ubuntu 20.04. I have tried exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, but still not working.

Comment: searching for a package by filename: `% apt-file search libcublas.so.11`
libcublas11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublas.so.11
...

Comment: the command returns empty, although I created a symbolic link in that directory

Comment: you can checkout all shared object dependencies with ldd: `ldd /path/to/some/libname.so`

Comment: in this case: ldd /path/to/libcublas.so.11 ?

Comment: supposing in your case it is `ldd /path/to/libnvinfer_plugin.so.8`